# MongoDB --keyFile has password, but which user?

Tags: mongodb

I write in my mongod, mongos, configdb -> --keyFile C:/secret.txt

secret.txt is a text -> `blabla`

How can I to use this password?

Thank you!

Comment: The keyfile doesn't contain a password. Give the following a read - it may help clarify: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Answer (score 2):

The [`keyfile`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.keyFile) value points to a file path for a "pre-shared key" that will be used for authentication between the members of your sharded cluster or replica set. This is effectively an internal "password" that can only be used by system processes, not by end users. See [Authentication Between MongoDB Instances](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#inter-process-auth-key-file) for more details.

Enabling `keyfile` also enables `auth` ([authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)) for your MongoDB deployment. To set up user accounts you need to:

- [Create a user administrator account](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/)
- [Add user account(s) with appropriate roles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/)